# Why can't perl multiply a decimal number correctly?

Tags: perl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$test = 1.30733;
$test = int($test * 100000);
print "test : " , $test ;
```

Results in 
test : 130732

Can someone tell me why?

Comment: it's a floating point issue. 1.30733 is actually 1.03732999999999999999 or similar internally.

Comment: Can you pipe it to `bc` instead?

Comment: Add `use bignum;` at the top of your file.  Might read [this Perl faq entry](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#Why-am-I-getting-long-decimals-(eg%2c-19.9499999999999)-instead-of-the-numbers-I-should-be-getting-(eg%2c-19.95)%3f)

Comment: [What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://floating-point-gui.de/)

Comment: Thx for taking the time to answer my question. I appreciate it.

Comment: and, also read why 0.999(9) == 1 (exactly)!    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.999...

Answer (score 0):

130733/100000 is a periodic number in binary just like 1/3 is a periodic number in decimal. It would take infinite storage to store it as a floating point number.

It's actually getting stored something a little less than 130733/100000.

Always use rounding when outputting floating point numbers, and always use a tolerance when comparing them.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. Rounding all the numbers after calculations..

Answer (score 0):

If you skipped the int() Perl would DWIM here:

```
> $x * 100000
130733
```